# Installing LAMP-server

Tags: lamp

I installed Ubuntu 16 some years ago, and I remembered an option during installation that allowed me to install a few other functions, such as LAMP. Why is that option removed, and what is the easiest way to install it (with just basic Ubuntu server knowledge)? I've tried `apt-get install lamp-server` as sugested by a google search, but the terminal replies 
`Unable to locate package lamp-server`.

Comment: I suspect you are remembering (and seeking) `tasksel`.

Comment: I don't remember having to type anything anywhere, it was an option during the Ubuntu setup, to include LAMP, Mailserver, SSH and some other features.

Answer (score 0):

The *absolute minimum* would be this:

0. Open Terminal (or connect to the machine via SSH)
1. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install Apache:

   ```
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
3. Ensure the Uncomplicated FireWall allows traffic:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"
   ```

   <sup>From here you can test that Apache is working by visiting the IP address of the system. For example, if you're installing on your local machine, you can use `http://127.0.0.1` in your browser of choice.</sup>
4. Install MySQL Server:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

   Once installed, you can interactively configure the database with:

   ```
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```
5. Install PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-dev php-json php-xml php-zip php-mbstring
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Some additional, common packages are included here. I you're not going to use JSON, XML, or ZIP compression, feel free to exclude them. The Multi-Byte string (`mbstring`) and development packages are strongly encouraged, though.</sup>
6. (Optional) Enable the Apache Headers and Redirect modules:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod redirect 
   sudo a2enmod headers
   ```
7. Restart Apache to ensure that everything is running:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

This will give you the bare minimum of a working LAMP stack. From here, you can begin working with MySQL to create accounts and databases or modify the Apache virtual host configuration files to better suit your purposes.